# Elasticsearch sink connector throws 403 forbidden exception when trying to create indices from topics

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

i am trying to create a sink connector to elastic cloud. This is the configuration of my Elasticsearch sink connector (with ksqldb).

```
create sink connector elastic_writer with (
'connector.class'='io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector',
'connection.url'='********',
'connection.username'='********',
'connection.password'='********',
'type.name'='kafka-connect',
'topics.regex'='sqlserver\.dbo\.*',
'schema.ignore'='true');
```

When i create the sink connector i first get this error.

```
[2020-11-02 08:56:37,480] INFO Index 'sqlserver.dbo.quotations' not found in local cache; checking for existence (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient)
[2020-11-02 08:56:37,486] INFO Index 'sqlserver.dbo.quotations' not found in Elasticsearch. Error message: 403 Forbidden (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient)
[2020-11-02 08:56:37,486] INFO Requesting Elasticsearch create index 'sqlserver.dbo.quotations' (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient)
[2020-11-02 08:56:37,494] INFO Index 'sqlserver.dbo.quotations' not found in local cache; checking for existence (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient)
[2020-11-02 08:56:37,503] INFO Index 'sqlserver.dbo.quotations' not found in Elasticsearch. Error message: 403 Forbidden (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient)
[2020-11-02 08:56:37,504] WARN Failed to create index sqlserver.dbo.quotations with attempt 1/6, will attempt retry after 62 ms. Failure reason: Could not create index 'sqlserver.dbo.quotations': 403 Forbidden (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient)
```

then it cycles through all of the retries untill i finally get the following error and the task gets killed.

```
[2020-11-02 08:56:40,245] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=ELASTIC_WRITER-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Could not create index 'sqlserver.dbo.quotations': 403 Forbidden
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.createIndex(JestElasticsearchClient.java:451)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.createIndices(JestElasticsearchClient.java:421)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchWriter.createIndicesForTopics(ElasticsearchWriter.java:374)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.open(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:131)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.openPartitions(WorkerSinkTask.java:614)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.access$1100(WorkerSinkTask.java:71)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask$HandleRebalance.onPartitionsAssigned(WorkerSinkTask.java:679)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.invokePartitionsAssigned(ConsumerCoordinator.java:293)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:430)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:440)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:359)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:513)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1268)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1230)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1210)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.pollConsumer(WorkerSinkTask.java:451)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:318)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:226)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[2020-11-02 08:56:40,246] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=ELASTIC_WRITER-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this problem? I've already tried to make the indices before creating the sink connector, however this didnt fix the problem and kafka connect threw the exact same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 403 exception is thrown when the elastic sink connector is unable to connect with the elastic service. Check your firewall settings and/or filters applied in the elastic cloud deployment